# Efficient way to search within unsorted array

Tags: arrays, database, sqlite, sorting, data-structures

I have an unsorted array A containing value within range 0 to 100. I have multiple query of format QUERY(starting array index, ending array index, startValue, endValue). I want to return array of indexes whose value lies within startValue and endValue. Naive approach is taking O(n) time for each query and i needed efficient algorithm. Also, query are not known initially.

Comment: Why tags *database* and *sqlite* are given? Are you using it?

Comment: there's not much you can do with a plain array A, unless you are willing to preprocess `A` and store some extra information in some other data structure

Comment: Worst case is indeed O(n). But the expected complexity is O(range), where `range` is the average range (i.e. `endIndex - startIndex + 1`). Are you allowed to preprocess your array and create a separate data structure to be used for queries? Note, though, that whatever you do, the worst case will still be O(n): somebody could present a query like (0, n, 0, 100), which would make you examine and return every element.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tradeoffs in terms of memory usage, preprocessing time and query time. Let *h* be the range of possible values (101 in your case). Ideally you would like your queries to take *O*(*m*) time, where *m* is the number of indexes returned. Here are some approaches.

1. [2-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Each array element *V*[*x*] = *y* corresponds to a 2-d point (*x*, *y*). Each query (*start*, *end*, *min*, *max*) corresponds to a range query in the 2-d tree between those boundaries. This implementation needs *O*(*n*) memory, *O*(*n* log *n*) preprocessing time and *O*(sqrt *n* + *m*) time per query (see the [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Complexity) section). Notably, this does not depend on *h*.
2. Sorted arrays + min-heap (Arguably an easier implementation if you roll your own).

   - Build *h* sorted arrays *P*<sub>0...*h*</sub> where *P*<sub>*k*</sub> is the array of positions where the value *k* occurs in the original array. This takes *O*(*n*) memory and *O*(*n*) preprocessing time.
   - Now we can answer in *O*(log *n*) (using binary search) queries of the form *next*(*pos*, *k*): "starting at position *pos*, where does the next value of *k* occur?"
   - To answer a query (*start*, *end*, *min*, *max*), begin by collecting *next*(*start*, *min*), *next*(*start*, *min* + 1), ..., *next*(*start*, *max*) and build a min-heap with them. This takes *O*(*h* log *n*) time. Then, while the minimum of the heap is at most *end*, remove it from the heap, add it to the list of indices to return, and add in its place the next element from its corresponding *P* array. This yields a complexity of O(*h* log *n* + *m* log *h*) per query.
3. I have two more ideas based on the [linearithmic approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query#Solution_using_constant_time_and_linearithmic_space) to range minimum queries, but they require *O*(*nh*) and *O*(*nh* log *h*) space respectively. The query time is improved to O(*m*). If that is not prohibitive, please let me know and I will edit the answer to elaborate.